# Cake php combine query condition

Tags: mysql, cakephp

**I need to change the following query to cake php Query format can any one here can guide me**

```
select Address1 + ' ' + Address2 as CompleteAddress from YourTable 
where Address1 + ' ' + Address2 like '%YourSearchString%'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   select Concat(Address1 ,' ', Address2) as CompleteAddress from YourTable 
   where Concat(Address1,' ',Address2) like '%YourSearchString%'
```

Comment: yahoo!!! Thanks a lot echo_Me!!!  i got an idea with your post and implemented and got output :)

Comment: **1. Added virutal user filed at Model public** 

public $virtualFields = array('full_addr' => 'CONCAT(Address1,' ',Address2)');

**2. Implemented the same in condition of the Cake php Query and make it simple.**

$this->User->find('list', array('conditions' => array(
                'User.full_addr LIKE'=> $this->request->data['userAddress'] . '%'
        )));